# Switch language in Typo3 10 with typoscript condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use the current TYPO3 10 LTS version. For some reason an external application uses content from our Typo3 and isn't able to use the normal language parameter L and his value 0 or 1.

In TYPo3 8 it wasn't a problem to get and switch the language with param ?lang=en.

In TYPO3 10 I checked out this and it doesn't work:

```
[request.getQueryParams()['lang'] == 'de']
config {
    sys_language_uid = 0
    language = de
    locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
    htmlTag_langKey = de
}
[END]

[request.getQueryParams()['lang'] == 'en']
config {
    sys_language_uid = 1
    language = en
    locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
    htmlTag_langKey = en
}
[END]
```

Do you have an idea to make this behaviour work again in Typo3 10?

Thanks and best regards,

Chris

Comment: I found in the documentation that it isn't able anymore to set the language over the typoscript configs shown in my first post:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#sitehandling-addinglanguages

Is there any new setting for this?

Comment: Another way to achieve this would be with .htaccess and modrewrite...

Comment: Parameters are not used to map to languages any more - Domain/URL are.
If .htaccess suffices for the URLs you need then that would be easiest. If you need a generic solution, you could have a Middleware redirect to the page in the requested language. You could take inspiration from the hreflang generation.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. If you define the languages in the site config.yaml it should auto switch already with /de and /en?